# Professor obligated to take the lab of the course whilst having the course

Tags: lab-course

In our university, the professor has obliged the students to take the lab and the course together. In this university the laboratory courses cannot be emergency dropped from a semester.

The laboratory has to be taken after or while having the course itself.  The course itself is three  credits and the lab course is one credit.  The professor uses the lab class for doing the assignments which were done using a simulation at home.

He claimed that the course together is complex enough to merit four credits.

There are some problems:

1. Those who have passed the course before and got the laboratory course this semester have to take the pressure of a four credit course while this is formally one of our rights in this university.
2. Those who need to do the emergency removal of the course cannot do it, because the lab course is required.

The professor is not argumentative and doesn't take steps to make the situation more tolerable.

He claims that if he didn't make the obligation to take the course a complex with its lab it wasn't something good for you and the current situation is a good point for you for being less under pressure due to these two being a complex. This is against what he claimed at the start of the course.

Who's wrong here? Should we start having talks with authorities?

Comment: You need to solve this with your university, we cannot help. Talk to the dean or the person responsible for the content of the programme.

Comment: Would you think about this differently if there was only one course in the registration system, a 4-credit lab+lecture course?

Comment: Hi Parsa, welcome to Ac.SE. I edited your post for English mostly, however, there are some things I cannot understand that I think will help people understand your problems better. Namely, "while this is formally one of our rights in this university" I don't understand as well as what is now the second-to-last paragraph.

Comment: For example, why are you bringing up the emergency drop ("remove")? Do you have a personal emergency that you believe merits this?

Answer (score 3):

It is not uncommon to have a lab section attached to the course and separate credit given for the lab section.  Indeed, in many cases it doesn't make much sense to register in the lab section without taking the course as the labs are quasi-dependent on the material covered in the course.

At least where I work, students who repeat a course with a lab section can get permission from the instructor to use their own lab marks in the current enrolment year.  This is at the discretion of the instructor and there are various situations where this permission is not granted.  Administration is not involved: the instructor just looks up their spreadsheet and copy-paste the marks from the previous year to the current year.  It is certainly not possible to do the lab separately from the course as a stand-alone credit, and credit for the lab is given concurrently with credit for the theory part of the course, and you cannot get credit for the lab without getting credit for the course.

There is nothing to do if you have an uncooperative instructor, except possibly plead your case to the administration, although this is unlikely to solve your problem in the short term unless the instructor is clearly in violation of university policy.

Answer (score 0):

I have had exactly this problem when teaching introductory physics classes. In my case, my concern was that desperate students were getting turned away from lecture because there were no spots in lab. Then a few weeks later when students were dropping the class, there were empty seats in both lecture and lab. Seemed like such a simple fix, but I banged on the pipes a little and was unable to fix it.

So on one hand, I agree this is a very annoying situation -- everything from the policy itself to your professor's attitude seem annoying. On the other hand, I seriously doubt you will be able to change this policy. By all means, write to the dean or department chair if you want to; they cannot fix problems that they don't know about. But unfortunately, I predict they will defer to your professor's judgment. And, be aware that if you complain about your professor before the class ends, that could lead to an awkward situation for the next few months.